# Plagiarism of Research Proposal Idea by Potential Supervisors

Tags: ethics

I really would like to know how to prevent a plagiarism of your idea or Research Proposal, when it is sent to several Universities and potential supervisors?  What can I do if one of the potential supervisors did not respond to me, nor did consider my research important, but later I notice that they are using my idea with other possible investigators?

What can I do in that case?

I am really frustrated and disappointed with that lack of ethics. I feel that this person stole my idea and my possible place in the University, and the possible fruits of my work and idea as well.

I really would appreciate your advice.
Thanks a lot for your wonderful website.

Comment: Probably you are ideas are not that groundbreaking that no one else can come up with them. It is likely that he came up with this idea independently.

Comment: Either your idea is not as groundbreaking, as Rüdiger says. Or else, if it is, don't send it around. Even if, say, 95% of the researchers are ethical, the probability of encountering one who isn't goes up as you send to more people. "Fruits of your work" - did you send them results?

Comment: Note that when submitting research proposals, many supervisors usually do not care about the specific idea itself, but rather whether you provide a good approach to execute the idea. As the others mentioned, it is rarely the case that a particular idea is new and groundbreaking by itself.

Answer (score 4):

I understand and completely share your frustration here. It feels awful when your application is rejected but later the same idea is used by a person you put some of your trust in.

I don't have a universal answer which helps to avoid such things. Sometimes people suggest to be vague in your proposal, but I don't think this is really a good idea. After all, when you have an idea, and you think it is good, you don't want to sound like you don't know what you're talking about. So, I don't think you should somehow tweak your proposal to make it less easy to plagiarise.

Instead, I would suggest to maybe do better research of potential supervisors before you send them your detailed proposal. Perhaps, do a small polite exchange of emails and check if they are even interested to have another PhD/postdoc at this moment? Look at their history of publications, read a few papers - are they really working in the area you want to work in? Look at author's lists - is there evidence that a potential supervisor  was a guest/gift author in many papers? Are there cases when they re-claim someone else's idea as their own (by doing minor modifications and changing the name, etc.) If possible, get in touch with their current postdocs/PhDs and check what they think about the transparency and ethics of the research/publication process in their group. Or simply try to arrange a small chat with the potential supervisor - sometimes five minutes face-to-face tell you more about a person than a year of email exchanges.

Good luck.

Comment: "Look at author's lists - is there evidence that a potential supervisor was a guest/gift author in many papers?", How do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

To be successful, your proposal needs to be related to the expertise of the supervisors.  So it is perfectly normal for the supervisor to do similar work if you do not end up working for them.  If it is for a PhD position, then it would not be unusual for the supervisor to direct the student to propose a particular topic or methodology.  It is common to find many people working on the same thing, but only those who make a good implementation get credit.

A research proposal, on its own, is not valuable research.  It is the implementation of the proposal which creates the value.  If you feel you have already completed the hard part of the project, what you have is not a research proposal, it is mostly finished research.

The answer to the question is:  you do not need to do anything.

Answer (score -1):

Insert a copyright statement in proposal document and in your email footnote. Also, to be on safe side always keep record of email exchange, especially the email you sent with proposal document.

Comment: The first part seems completely pointless.

Comment: I agree with @TobiasKildetoft - there seems to be a widespread belief that copyright is an anti-plagiarism measure whereas it is really about _rights of distribution_. Something can be intellectually plagiarized and still not breach copyright. Conversely, if I typed up someone else's book and tried to sell it _while still clearly stating the original author_, that is not plagiarism but it would probably breach copyright

Comment: I don't think that will really prevent any issues. Plus, it may send a wrong message to the receiver.

Comment: I saw this practice done by professor from MIT. I was engaged in discussion about possible visit to his lab and he shared with me their on going work detail with a copyright statement "All rights reserved".